# CSS and js template, open window in same window

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I did download:

https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page238/resume

Under "my projects" there is images, when pressing one there will open a new window but as the same side. But when clicking on another image the same page will open. I want to do different pages with different images. I have tried changing the "id" to test01 on the "page" and the href""#test01". But it does not work unless I use the original "Animatedmodular".

How do I make multiple "popups" but in the same window?

I don't know If I made this right. I tried to get the script to work with the images. But if you look on the "Live Demo" and scroll down and press the image "Mockups in seconds" and then "Floating Mockups", they both open the same window, I want them to be be "linked" to different window. I want the second image to open the "". I hope someone understand the script what I wanted to do and how to fix it. I haven't been doing homepages since the 90's. So I'm glad for all the help I can get. :)

```css
.animatedModal-on .close-popup-modal {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <!-- single work -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6  fashion logo">
    <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal" class="portfolio_item"> <img src="img/22-00.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
        <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
          <div class="item_info"> <span>test.</span> <em>test </em> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- end single work -->

  <!-- single work -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 ads graphics">
    <a id="demo02" href="#demo2" class="portfolio_item"> <img src="img/19-00.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
        <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
          <div class="item_info"> <span>test</em> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end single work -->
                            
                            <!-- single work -->
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 photography">
                                <a id="demo03" href="#03korsett" class="portfolio_item"> <img src="img/01-00.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
                                    <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                                        <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                            <div class="item_info"> <span>test</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end single work -->
                            
                            
                            <!--DEMO01-->
    <div id="animatedModal" class="popup-modal">
        <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID -->
        <div id="btn-close-modal" class="close-animatedModal close-popup-modal"> <i class="ion-close-round"></i> </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="portfolio-padding">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h2>Vtest</h2>
                        <div class="h-50"></div>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <br />
                        <br /> <img src="img/22-00.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <p>Atest</p>
                        <br />
                        <br /> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
                                
                            <!--DEMO02-->
    <div id="demo2" class="popup-modal">
        <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID -->
        <div id="btn-demo2" class="close-demo2 close-demo2"> <i class="ion-close-round"></i> </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="portfolio-padding">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h2>Vtest</h2>
                        <div class="h-50"></div>
                        <p>test</p>
                        <br />
                        <br /> <img src="img/22-00.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <p>Atest</p>
                        <br />
                        <br /> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Color and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code you have tried so far. We need a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to work with

Comment: Thank you. I will post the code tomorrow. I'm not on the computer right now. Should I post the full code or just the once with the links and the page? Also do I need to post the js-files?

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{   
    
    /* get id of form to work with */
    
    $('.show-lookup').click(function()
    {
        var pairedId = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        var lookupToDisplay = '#lookup-' + pairedId[1];
        $('.overlay').show();
        $(lookupToDisplay).show();
        $('.js-popup-focus').focus();
    });
    
/* put value selected in lookup into field in main form */
    
    $('.lookup-popup input').on('change', function() 
    {  
        var fieldname = $(this).attr('name');
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        var selOption = $('input[name='+fieldname+']:checked').val(); 
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).val(selOption);
    });
    
/* for checkbox version, append selected values to field in main form */    
    
    $('.lookup-multiselect input').on('change', function() 
    {  
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        //event.preventDefault();
        var selOptions = $(".category input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
        }).get(); // <----
        //console.log(selOptions);
        var selectedString = selOptions.toString();
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).val(selOptions);
    });
    
    $('.close-button').click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        var pairedId = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('-');
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $("#entry-"+pairedId[1]).focus();
    });
});
```

```css
button {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  height: 36px;
  min-width: 64px;
  font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: box-shadow;
  transition: box-shadow .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,1,1),background-color .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1),color .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.lookup-popup, .lookup-multiselect {
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6em;
    left: 35%;
    width: 70%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    background: rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, Calibri, Helvetica, sans serif;
  padding: 2em;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: #333;
}
.lookup-popup {
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    left: 25%;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<input type="text" class="order-entry js-initial-focus" id="entry-r1" placeholder="place" tabindex="1">
        <button class="show-lookup" id="popup-r1" tabindex="2">Search</button>
        </p>
        <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="lookup-popup" id="lookup-r1">
            <button class="close-button right"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
            <strong>Select...</strong>
            <form action="#" id="form-r1" name="form-r1" method="post">
                    <input class="js-popup-focus" type="radio" name="place" id="antwerp" value="Antwerp" tabindex="3"> <label for="antwerp">Antwerp</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="berlin" value="Berlin" tabindex="3"> <label for="berlin">Berlin</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="cairo" value="Cairo" tabindex="3"> <label for="cairo">Cairo</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="duss" value="D&uuml;sseldorf" tabindex="3"> <label for="duss">D&uuml;sseldorf</label><br>
            </form>
        </div>
        
  <p>      
<input type="text" class="order-entry js-initial-focus" id="entry-r2" placeholder="place" tabindex="1">
        <button class="show-lookup" id="popup-r2" tabindex="2">Search</button>
        </p>
        <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="lookup-popup" id="lookup-r2">
            <button class="close-button right"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
            <strong>Select...</strong>
            <form action="#" id="form-r2" name="form-r2" method="post">
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="exeter" value="Exeter" tabindex="3"> <label for="exeter">Exeter</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="frankfurt" value="Frankfurt" tabindex="3"> <label for="frankfurt">Frankfurt</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="ghent" value="Ghent" tabindex="3"> <label for="ghent">Ghent</label><br>
<input class="js-popup-focus" type="radio" name="place" id="hamburg" value="Hamburg" tabindex="3"> <label for="hamburg">Hamburg</label><br>
            </form>
        </div>
```

If you use the classes and ids provided, the jQuery will iterate through the various form elements and match them with their respective pop-ups.

Use entry-r1, entry-r2 etc as the id for the input fields. Use lookup-r1, lookup-r2 etc as the id for the corresponding popup. Use form-r1, form-r2 etc as the id for the form in the lookup-popup.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the id of your new modal in your css :

```
.animatedModal-on .demo2-on .close-popup-modal {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and in your custom.js, you need to define your modal taget as follow :

```
$("#demo02").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: "demo2"
});
```